# Rails 4 : Execute code after thread execution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `Thread.new {}` which calls a system program, and I want the view (it's a `responds_to` in JSON) to be returned to the user **after** the thread is terminated, but I don't want to have the entire website blocked, waiting the program to finish.

Any ideas to do that ?

Comment: try use http://puma.io/ server without `Thread`

Comment: If I use Puma, the controller function will wait for the thread to be finished before rendering the view without blocking the website itself ?

Comment: it will wait anyway, but it will not block other users to interract with your website

Comment: Just tested. Removed all `Thread`-related things in my function. Puma seems to block when I launch my program (which takes between 5 and 10 seconds to execute). Launched with `puma -t 8:32 -w --preload`. What's wrong here ?